# when does the onerror event get triggered when used with img tag in angular?

Tags: html, angular, image, webp, onerror

I just wanted to know when is this event triggered ? Does it get triggered when an image format given in source is not compatible in a particular browser.For example when a webp image link is given in source and the browser does not support webp. Does onerror event get triggered then ?

Answer (score 0):

The onerror event is triggered if an error occurs while loading an external file (e.g. a document or an image).

`<img src="image.gif" onerror="myFunction()">`

For example when a webp image link is given in source and the browser does not support webp. Does onerror event get triggered then -> No onerror doesn't get triggered

[image]

Comment: Could you please tell why it wouldn't be triggered ? Cause its essentially an error occuring when an image is loaded right ?